# How to raise an Azure DevOps Support Ticket

Tags: server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-agent

I'd like to raise an Azure DevOps support ticket for an issue we're experiencing with a number of agents (they seem to go down overnight for no reason).

Would appreciate some advice on where and how to raise this ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask your question here: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html). They try to reproduce your problem and communicate with the product team to resolve it or include a new fix to next releases.